Alien invasion film involving a pool shooting?
It's a post 2000 Alien Invasion movie. I had seen this one scene where a star actor leads a team of US Army officers or Marines into a town full of alien creatures. There is a part where an alien jumps out of a swimming pool but the team kills it.
I also remember that one of their team members is injured (probably got a burn near his forehead) and to patch him up, they enter a evacuated house which has that swimming pool.
When the team is walking down the main road of the town, they try to locate the aliens who used to move from one rooftop of a building to another.
They also find some sort of weak region of the alien body and are asked to shoot it there.
Does someone know this movie?

@cde I checked out Slither. It wasn't the one I watched.

So not Nathan Fillion/Slither, but it still makes it unlikely to be Matt Damon, as Damon hasn't done any alien invasion type film as far as I know. A quick look at his IMDb filmography shows nothing fitting that genre. Closest thing to Alien movie he has done was a voice for Titan A.E.

Okay. I guess I have goofed up. I am editing out Matt Damon. Thanks.

The pool scene described is from Battle: Los Angeles:

A 2011 American military science fiction war film directed by Jonathan Liebesman. The film is set in modern-day Los Angeles and follows a retiring Marine Staff Sergeant played by Aaron Eckhart who must go back into the line of duty to lead a platoon of U.S. Marines, a Hospital corpsman, isolated U.S. Army soldiers and a U.S. Air Force sergeant during a global alien invasion.

The scene can be seen here:



Further in the movie is the finding of the weak spot:

The Marines commandeer a city bus for evacuation. They also vivisect a wounded alien with the help of Michele and find a vulnerable spot in its torso.


Watched the complete movie. It was good.
